# Loop Through Table & Add Values

Tags: t-sql

I am writing a stored procedure to loop through a table, insert the values into a temporary table & then eventually I will loop through the temporary table & add the values.

So far I have the first loop written which will insert values into the temporary table.

I am getting this error...

```
There is already an object named '#testtable' in the database.
```

Here is my code:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

DECLARE @TestID int,
        @TestValue int,
        @sum int

CREATE TABLE #testtable (TestID int,
                    TestValue int)

DECLARE loop CURSOR FOR
SELECT TestValue
FROM tblTest
WHERE TestID > 1


OPEN loop
FETCH NEXT FROM loop INTO @TestID,@TestValue

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #temp (TestID, TestValue) values (@TestID, @TestValue)

    FETCH NEXT FROM loop INTO @TestID,@TestValue
END

CLOSE loop
DEALLOCATE loop

    SELECT @TestID FROM #testtable WHERE @TestID > 1
```

Comment: This is a job that shoujld NEVER be done in a cursopr. DO  NOT EVER INSERT,UPDATE OR DELETE using a cursor http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that this is what is happening:

- Open a **new** session in SSMS
- Copy over the above script
- Run it and it works. This is because the #temp table was just created.
- Immediately run it again, or perhaps modify the script a bit and run it again. This time it fails with that error message, because the #temp table was recated in the first pass *and has not yet been dropped.*

To avoid this problem in your script, at the bottom of the script add:

```
DROP TABLE #testtable
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Philip. I am now getting this error: Invalid object name '#tempTable'.

Comment: Can't help you there -- "#tempTable" does not appear anywhere in your posted script.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a cursor to populate the temporary table, how about just creating the temp table and populating it in one go like this ?

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#testtable') is not null drop table #testtable

SELECT TESTID, TestValue 
INTO #testtable
FROM tblTest WHERE TestID > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the sum then this should do it

```
    SELECT sum(TestValue)
    FROM tblTest
    WHERE TestID > 1
```